# Is there a cleaner way of writing this jQuery code to swap images?

Tags: jquery

I have this code that basically swaps an image every time the related checkbox is clicked. However, the jQuery code seems quite repetitive and I'd be interested to know how I could write this to be cleaner.

```js
$(function() {

  $('#switch1').change(function(){
      if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
          $('#image1').attr('src','image1-swap-png');
        } else {
      $('#image1').attr('src','image1-swap-png');
        };
    });
  
  $('#switch2').change(function(){
      if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
          $('#image2').attr('src','image2-swap-png');
        } else {
      $('#image2').attr('src','image2-swap-png');
        };
    });
  
  $('#switch3').change(function(){
      if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
          $('#image3').attr('src','image3-swap-png');
        } else {
      $('#image3').attr('src','image3-swap-png');
        };
    });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3>First example</h3>
    <div>
      <input type="checkbox" id="switch1">
      <label>Checkbox</label>
    </div>
    <img id="image1" src="image1.png">
    
    <h3>Second example</h3>
    <div>
      <input type="checkbox" id="switch2">
      <label>Checkbox</label>
    </div>
    <img id="image2" src="image2.png">
    
    <h3>Third example</h3>
    <div>
      <input type="checkbox" id="switch3">
      <label>Checkbox</label>
    </div>
    <img id="image3" src="image3.png">
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: If my answer was helpful, please upvote and make as the right answer. Thanks in advance

Comment: Code in you `if` and `else` statement are same. You can eliminate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The technique you're looking for is called Don't Repeat Yourself, or DRY. To do apply that to the code you've shown you can amend the HTML to use a combination of common classes, to group elements by behaviour, and `data` attributes, to place custom metadata on an element.

From there you can use a single event handler for all elements, with the differences applied through the data attributes. Try this:

```js
jQuery($ => {
  $('.switch').on('change', e => {
    let $image = $(e.target).closest('div').next('.image');
    $image.prop('src', $image.data(e.target.checked ? 'checked' : 'unchecked'));
  });
});
```

```css
img { width: 50px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3>First example</h3>
<div>
  <input type="checkbox" class="switch">
  <label>Checkbox</label>
</div>
<img class="image" src="https://i.imgur.com/dC9QaX4.png" data-checked="https://i.imgur.com/1uN7N7b.png" data-unchecked="https://i.imgur.com/dC9QaX4.png">

<h3>Second example</h3>
<div>
  <input type="checkbox" class="switch">
  <label>Checkbox</label>
</div>
<img class="image" src="https://i.imgur.com/dC9QaX4.png" data-checked="https://i.imgur.com/1uN7N7b.png" data-unchecked="https://i.imgur.com/dC9QaX4.png">
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use jquery [`selectors`](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_selectors.asp) [attribute selector `[]`](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/sel_attribute_beginning_value.asp) with `^=` which will match attribute value starting with provided value.

Then find parent div with `closest('div')` and then next img element with `.next('img')` and update its `src`.

As per sample in your question there is an identical code inside `if else` block, so I haven't added `if else`.

```js
// get all elements whose id starts with switch
$('[id^=switch]').change(function() {
  // get id of current input and remove switch. Rest part will be index
  let index = $(this).attr('id').replace('switch', '');

  // you can add $(this).is(':checked') if needed

  // find parent div and then next img element & set src
  $(this).closest('div').next('img').attr('src', 'image' + index + '-swap-png');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3>First example</h3>
<div>
  <input type="checkbox" id="switch1">
  <label>Checkbox</label>
</div>
<img id="image1" src="image1.png">

<h3>Second example</h3>
<div>
  <input type="checkbox" id="switch2">
  <label>Checkbox</label>
</div>
<img id="image2" src="image2.png">

<h3>Third example</h3>
<div>
  <input type="checkbox" id="switch3">
  <label>Checkbox</label>
</div>
<img id="image3" src="image3.png">
```

Answer (score 0):

Store all the switch elements in an array.

```
const switches = [$('#switch1'), $('#switch2'), $('#switch3')];
```

Iterate over the array. Use the index + 1 to get image number. Put the image number into the image id selector using backticks.

```
switches.forEach((switch, i) => {
   if (switch.is(':checked')) {
      $(`#image${i}`).attr('src',`image${i}e-swap-png`);
   } else {
      $(`#image${i}`).attr('src',`image${i}-swap-png`);
   };
})
```

Comment: Firstly, if you're going to do it this way, which you shouldn't as it'll break as soon as you add a fourth element, then just merge the selectors in to a single jQuery object: `$('#switch1, #switch2, #switch3')`. This way you don't need to loop through them manually. Secondly, there's no `change` event handler here, so the code will only ever run once when the page loads.